# Having some problems with Project Euler 31

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-3.6

I've been working on solving [Problem 31](https://projecteuler.net/problem=31) from [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net). I'm almost finished, but my code is giving me what I know is the wrong answer. My dad showed the right answer, and mine is giving me something *completely* wrong.

```py
coins = (1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200)
amount = 200
def ways(target, avc):    
    target = amount
    if avc <= 1:
          return 1
    res = 0
    while target >= 0:
        res = res + ways(target, avc-1)
        target = target - coins[avc]
    return res
print(ways(amount, 7))
```

This is the answer I get.

```
284130
```

The answer is supposed to 73682.
EDIT: Thank you to everyone who answered my question.  Thanks to all of you, I have figured it out!

Comment: could you elaborate with an example of the expected and actual result of your code?

Comment: Maybe it's the `target = amount`. Doesn't seem like that should be there.

Comment: You should instead post on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) I think it suits better your needs.

Comment: @cglacet: no, please not. They need code that works. This code does not work

Comment: You'll have to define work, because it does run without any error. It's an algorithmic question.

Comment: @aronquemarr Whenever I do that, it would give me something like 3276 or something.  It is supposed to give me 73682.  If you're wondering, it is the puesdocode shown on the sheet Project Euler allows people who have solved the problem to download.

Comment: @cglacet On Code Review we tend to say "works as intended". It doesn't matter if it compiles or not, all that matters is the code does what you want it to do. This clearly does not output the correct number so it's broken.

Comment: If nothing is wrong about a code then why even bother asking for help. The definition you give is very subjective as is depends on what you intend. If I intend to output an integer, this function works perfectly fine. On the other hand you could never ask for improving performances, because as soon as you ask for performances improvements you admit that the code doesn't "work as intended". This is sterile. I was just suggesting that code review questions tends to go to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of here.

Comment: @cglacet: IMHO this question is asking for debugging help

Comment: You could also consider [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) as this is "easy" to solve without coding anything.

Comment: No, the algorithm is off, so it's not debugging.

Comment: @cglacet It's not subjective, if you have a problem with Code Review's rules then please voice this on [Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/). The question as is will only get closed on Code Review.

Comment: I have no problem with it, I just say it's very subjective.

Comment: But this should be closed on stackoverflow too, so instead of arguing about why this shouldn't belong to codereview give the OP a place to ask for help …

Answer (score 2):

I see several ways how you can improve the way you're working on problems:

- Copy the task description into your source code. This will make you more independent from Internet resources. That allows you to work offline. Even if the page is down or disappears completely, it will enable someone else understanding what problem you're trying to solve.
- Use an IDE that does proper syntax highlighting and gives you hints what might be wrong with your code. The IDE will tell you what @aronquemarr mentioned in the comments:

  [image: Unused parameter]
- There's also a thing called *magic numbers*. Many of the numbers in your code can be explained, but why do you start with an `avc` of 7?. Where does that number come from? 7 does not occur in the problem description.
- Use better naming, so *you* understand better what your code does. What does `avc` stand for? If you think it's `available_coins`, that's not correct. There are 8 different coins, not 7.
- If it still does not work, reduce the problem to a simpler one. Start with the most simple one you can think of, e.g. make only 1 type of coin available and set the amount to 2 cent. There should only be 1 solution.
- To make sure this simple result will never break, introduce an assertion or unit test. They will help you when you change the code to work with larger datasets. They will also change the way you write code. In your case you'll find that accessing the variable `coins` from an outer scope is probably not a good idea, because it will break your assertion when you switch to the next level. The change that is needed will make your methods more self-contained and robust.
- Then, increase the difficulty by having 2 different coins etc.

  Examples for the first assertions that I used on this problem:

  ```py
  # Only 1 way of making 1 with only a 1 coin of value 1
  assert(find_combinations([1], 1) == 1)
  # Still only 1 way of making 1 with two coins of values 1 and 2
  assert(find_combinations([1,2], 1) == 1)
  # Two ways of making 2 with two coins of values 1 and 2
  assert(find_combinations([1,2], 2) == 2)
  ```
- As soon as the result does no longer match your expectation, use the debugger and step through your code. After every line, check the values in the debugger against the values that you think they should be.

  One time, the debugger will be your best friend.  And you can never imagine how you did stuff without it. You just need to learn how to use it.

Comment: Thank you, the only reason I had seven, was because I knew there were 8 coins, but python starts with 0, so I had to have seven.  Avc does stand for available coins.  If I used 8, I'd get a indexing error.

Comment: @NocturnalChild: that's a good observation. The name can then be `maximum_index` for example. And it should not be set to 7 but to `len(coins)-1`. People then know that the number 7 depends on the number of available coins and is not a value that *always* needs to be 7.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, read [Thomas Weller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62564586/2531987). They give some *excellent* suggestions as to how to improve your coding and problem solving.

Secondly, your code works, and gives the correct answer after the following changes:

- As suggested, remove the `target = amount` line. You're resigning the argument of the function to global `amount` on each call (even on the recursive calls). Having removed that the answer comes up to `3275` - still *not* the right answer.
- The other thing you have to remember is that Python is 0-indexed. Therefore, your simplest case condition ought to read `if avc <= 0: ...` (not `<=1`).

Having made these two changes, your code gives the correct answer. Here is your code with these changes:

```py
coins = (1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200)
amount = 200
def ways(target, avc):
    if avc <= 0:
        return 1
    res = 0
    while target >= 0:
        res = res + ways(target, avc-1)
        target = target - coins[avc]
    return res
print(ways(amount, 7))
```

Lastly, there are plenty of Project Euler answers [out there](https://github.com/nayuki/Project-Euler-solutions/blob/master/python/p031.py?ts=4). Having solved the yourself, it might be useful to have a look at what others did. For reference, I have not actually solved this Project Euler before, so I had to do that first. [Here](https://gist.github.com/MarcinKonowalczyk/accef8941121470d8e67273437b62721) is my solution. I've added a pile of comments on top of it to explain what it does.

#### EDIT

I've just noticed something quite worrying: Your code (after fixes) works only if the first element of `coins` is 1. All the other elements can be shuffled:

```
# This still works ok
coins = (1,2,200,10,20,50,100,5)
# But this does not
coins = (2,1,5,10,20,50,100,200)
```

To ensure that this is always the case, you can just do the following:

```py
coins = ... # <- Some not necessarily sorted tuple
coins = tuple(sorted(coins))
```

In principle there are a few other issues. Your solution breaks for non-unique values `coins`, and  which don't include `1`. The former you could fix with the use of [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), and the latter by modifying your `if avc <= 0:` case (check for the divisibility of the target by the remaining coin). Here is you piece of code with these changes implemented. I've also renamed the variables and the function to be a bit easier to read, and used `coins` as the argument, rather that `avc` pointer (which, by the way, I could not stop reading as [avec](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Avec)):

```py
unique = lambda x: sorted(set(x)) # Sorted unique list
def find_combinations(target, coins):
    ''' Find the number of ways coins can make up the target amount '''
    coins = unique(coins)
    if len(coins)==1: # Only one coin, therefore just check divisibility
        return 1 if not target%coins[0] else 0 
    combinations = 0
    while target >= 0:
        combinations += find_combinations(target, coins[:-1])
        target -= coins[-1]
    return combinations

coins = [2,1,5,10,20,50,100,200] # <- Now works
amount = 200

print(find_combinations(amount, coins))
```